# How to access struct fields pointers inside another struct and write correctly?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, embedded

I have the following structs (from a library I'm using) with some fields and I would like to assign with OR operation a new value. But I'm debugging and I can't see how anything is writing there in stm32l4xx_hal_tim.c file:

```
 typedef struct
 {
   TIM_TypeDef              *Instance;     /*!< Register base address  */
   TIM_Base_InitTypeDef     Init;          /*!< TIM Time Base required parameters */
   HAL_TIM_ActiveChannel    Channel;       /*!< Active channel                    */
   DMA_HandleTypeDef        *hdma[7];      /*!< DMA Handlers array This array is accessed by a @ref DMA_Handle_index */
   HAL_LockTypeDef          Lock;          /*!< Locking object                    */
   __IO HAL_TIM_StateTypeDef   State;         /*!< TIM operation state               */
 }TIM_HandleTypeDef;


typedef struct
{
  __IO uint32_t CR1;         /*!< TIM control register 1,                   Address offset: 0x00 */
  __IO uint32_t CR2;         /*!< TIM control register 2,                   Address offset: 0x04 */
  __IO uint32_t SMCR;        /*!< TIM slave mode control register,          Address offset: 0x08 */
  __IO uint32_t DIER;        /*!< TIM DMA/interrupt enable register,        Address offset: 0x0C */
  __IO uint32_t SR;          /*!< TIM status register,                      Address offset: 0x10 */
  __IO uint32_t EGR;         /*!< TIM event generation register,            Address offset: 0x14 */
  __IO uint32_t CCMR1;       /*!< TIM capture/compare mode register 1,      Address offset: 0x18 */
  __IO uint32_t CCMR2;       /*!< TIM capture/compare mode register 2,      Address offset: 0x1C */
  __IO uint32_t CCER;        /*!< TIM capture/compare enable register,      Address offset: 0x20 */
  __IO uint32_t CNT;         /*!< TIM counter register,                     
 } TIM_TypeDef;
```

I have a part of code where I defined: TIM_HandleTypeDef  TIMER_Struct;

And I would like to access the field "CR1" of TIM_TypeDef struct that is "*Instance" field of TIM_HandleTypeDef. So I have done it by this way in a function DRV_TIMER_init():

```
  #include "main.h"
  #include "stm32l4xx_hal_tim.h"

  uint32_t uwPrescalerValue = 0;
  TIM_HandleTypeDef TIMER_Struct;
  void DRV_TIMER_init(void);

 int main(void)
 {  

   DRV_TIMER_init();
   while(1)
   {

   }

 }

 //where uint32_t SystemCoreClock = 4000000; in other system source file.
 void DRV_TIMER_init(void)
 {
  uwPrescalerValue = (uint32_t)(SystemCoreClock / 1000000) - 1;
  TIMER_Struct.Init.Period            = 100 - 1;
  TIMER_Struct.Init.Prescaler         = uwPrescalerValue;
  TIMER_Struct.Init.ClockDivision     = 0; // these accesses work

  TIMER_Struct.Instance -> CR1 |= 0x01 << 3; // this no works

 }
```

Even if I write directly:

```
 TIMER_Struct.Instance -> CR1 = 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

It stills without having effect.

I think It could be a fact that I'm not controlling appropiately the pointer access or similar. But I don't see how can I access and modify the content of the commented field. Since I can see (debug mode) how the rest of struct fields updates are writen correctly.

Any correction suggested here?

```
TIMER_Struct.Instance -> CR1 = 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

I try different ways to get it with no success. I need new ideas.

Comment: Advice: get rid of that STlib HAL bloatware and write to the registers directly. Write drivers to abstract the hardware. Wrt your question: read [ask], provide a [mcve]. After four months., you should know how it works.

Comment: @Olaf unfurtunately I can't choose this option. Using HAL_lib is a project spec and all the fw I'm working with has been developed some months ago, based on HAL_libs. However, I would like to know if I have done something wrong with my access way in order to learn how to face it in a future case.

Comment: Did you create an object for `TIMER_Struct.Instance` to point to? Please present your [MCVE].

Comment: No, I don't.  If I must create an object TIMER_Struct.Instance I will like to understand why if it possible.Now I'm changing a bit the example.  It will be updated soon. Thanks. Just let me some minutes.

Comment: Probably you didn't initialize the struct correctly. You are accessing the member correctly so the cause is something outside the posted code.

Comment: I always use the CMSIS bindings to write to registers. This should work `TIM1->CR1=0xFFFFFFFF` . No HAL required for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to define `TIMER_Struct.Instance`

```
TIM_HandleTypeDef TIMER_Struct;
TIMER_Struct.Instance = TIM1;
//Now you can access TIMER_Struct.Instance
TIMER_Struct.Instance->CR1 = (uint32_t)0xFFFFFFFF;
```

But I prefer to use CMSIS for writing to registers. No need for the HAL. With CMSIS writing to a register could look like:

```
TIM1->CR1=(uint32_t)0xFFFFFFFF
```

Comment: Sorry, I used the two methods but it stills without effects.

Comment: Have a look at the example projects from STM32CubeL4 and try to get them running before writing your own code. As i can see you are missing quite a few things here. You never configure your SystemClock. I can't see a call to `HAL_Init()`. Is the clock for the timer enabled? ( `__HAL_RCC_TIMxx_CLK_ENABLE()` macro)

Comment: Timer runs correctly. I only want to change a bit of updates bits configuration. There is no example for timer in CubeL4. And the other ones I have seen doesn't treat the matter I have woth pointers. And yes I have clock config. But I must to minimize the example in order to show directly the matter I need to solve. Pointer treatment and struct fields accesses.  I'm not able to write into the timer config registers throught HAL structs.

Comment: That's weird, I can't reproduce the issue on my stm32f7. The only restriction I can find in the reference manual of the stm32l4 would be: "The 32-bit peripheral registers have to be written by words (32 bits). All other peripheral registers have to be written by half-words (16 bits) or words (32 bits)." - So my last idea is to try explicitly cast the value to a `uint32_t` since that should work for every register.

Answer (score 0):

```
TIM_TypeDef              *Instance;
```

is just a pointer which is not pointing to anywhere so you can't dereference it

you have defined somewhere in the lib a macro like this:

```
#define TIM    (TIM_TypeDef*)0xDEADBEEF;
```

this is how you map the registers to the memory

try modifying your code like this:

```
TIMER_Struct.Instance = (TIM_Typedef*)0xDEADBEEF;
```

or just

```
TIMER_Struct.Instance = TIM;
```

than

```
 TIMER_Struct.Instance -> CR1 |= 0x01 << 3;
```

should work

Comment: And after     TIMER_Struct.Instance = TIM; line what should I do in order to write in CR1?

Comment: after TIMER_Struct.Instance = TIM;  the line TIMER_Struct.Instance -> CR1 |= 0x01 << 3; should work

Comment: if you are not allowed to use HAL structs you can do something like this:look how man bits is the CR register,let's say it's 32 bits,look what is the starting address of this register, try something like this -  #define TIM_CR1      ( * ( (volatile unsigned int*)0xstarting address) ) than just write TIM_CR1 |=0xFFFFFFFF;

Comment: The fact is that the Hal files define TIM7 addresses here as:
 ((TIM_TypeDef *)0x1400U)+((uint32_t)0x40000000U) , hence I did: TIMER_Struct.Instance = ((TIM_TypeDef *)0x1400U)+((uint32_t)0x40000000U) ; as you said before. But then all instance registers got: 0xFFFFFFF after debugging this line, something crasy. I will try your last alternative.

Comment: are you sure this is the correct macro?I think it should be something like this:((TIM_TypeDef *)(0x1400U + 0x40000000U))

Comment: I will show you how I found it and then you can correct my interpretation if needed: #define TIM7                ((TIM_TypeDef *) TIM7_BASE) #define TIM7_BASE             (APB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x1400U) #define APB1PERIPH_BASE        PERIPH_BASE #define PERIPH_BASE           ((uint32_t)0x40000000U) /*!< Peripheral base address */

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142632/discussion-between-martin-and-eugenia-suarez).

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. First you must enable the peripheral clock. If not, there won't be any effect over timer registers, because the pointer structs fields were pointing directly to the hardware registers allocation. This was the cause why I can't see any update when watching my struct var at debugging.

I was enabling clk (with hal_xxx_init()) after writing to the allocation. That was my mistake.

Here in this part of code is the correction:

```
//where uint32_t SystemCoreClock = 4000000; in other system source file.
void DRV_TIMER_init(void)
{
  uwPrescalerValue = (uint32_t)(SystemCoreClock / 1000000) - 1;
  TIMER_Struct.Init.Period            = 100 - 1;
  TIMER_Struct.Init.Prescaler         = uwPrescalerValue;
  TIMER_Struct.Init.ClockDivision     = 0; // these accesses work

  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&TIMER_Struct) != HAL_OK)
  {
     /* Initialization Error */
     TIM_Error_Handler();
  }

  TIMER_Struct.Instance -> CR1 |= 0x01 << 3; // this works now

}
```

If you try to put the last sentence before the:

```
HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&TIMER_Struct);
```

no

```
TIMER_Struct.Instance -> CR1 = xxx; //write mode register acces
```

will have effect.